# Django 1.11: Python 3.6 Upgrade causes issues with SSL connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, upgrade, python-3.6, django-1.11

I just upgraded my Django 1.10 (Python 3.5) app to Django 1.11 (Python 3.6) in my MacOS Sierra.

Most things still work, but I realized that SSL connections are not working the way they were before. I noticed it with some issues with my AWS S3 services and `python manage.py collectstatic`. These features are not connecting/being authenticated with AWS.

This is the first time there I am dealing with an update for my Django app, so I'm not so sure about what is the right way dealing with those issues.

I did some research and found out that it was an expected issue coming from a Mac using python 3.6.

Does anyone know if it is worth the trouble finding a solution for this or **is it better to just switch back to python 3.5?**

According to Python 3.6 ReadMe.rft:

**Certificate verification and OpenSSL**

***NEW*** This variant of Python 3.6 now includes its own private copy of OpenSSL 1.0.2.  Unlike previous releases, the deprecated Apple-supplied OpenSSL libraries are no longer used.  This also means that the trust certificates in system and user keychains managed by the Keychain Access application and the security command line utility are no longer used as defaults by the Python ssl module.  For 3.6.0, a sample command script is included in /Applications/Python 3.6 to install a curated bundle of default root certificates from the third-party certifi package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi).  If you choose to use certifi, you should consider subscribing to the project's email update service to be notified when the certificate bundle is updated.
The bundled pip included with the Python 3.6 installer has its own default certificate store for verifying download connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I realized what was wrong with my project.

I was using django-storages-redux alongside with boto.
Now I had to update to boto3 and use the django-storages library.